# How should connect my light to the wires in these three cables?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My house was built in 80s. I have a light fixture I want to mount with live (black)and neutral (white) and ground. Question is the two white wires bundled are neutral. The other 4 are confusing. 3 of the others have paint markings indicating they are hot and one black wire with no paint. I wired it wrong cause the light turns on but at the switch won’t turn off

[image]

Comment: FYI, 80s wiring is essentially modern. Not much has changed since then except the requirement that a neutral wire be provided at each switch.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a standard switch loop and a cable that goes out to another part of the circuit.

It's basically this with an extra cable coming in, which would simply be connected by color to the supply cable wires.

[image]

You'll have to do some sleuthing with your multi-meter to see what's what.

Answer (score 2):

Take the three wires with the marking on them and wire nut them together. Take the remaining white and black wires and connect them to the white and black wires from the fixture.

One marked black wire is the feed along with one of the bundled white wires. The other marked black is more than likely a feed to another location along with the other bundled white wire. The marked white is a hot to the switch and the black (no mark) is the switched hot.